# Castle Windsor Interceptor not working with Method-Level attribute

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, aop, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a Castle Interceptor that I'm trying to apply via attributes.  It's working great when I apply my Interceptor attribute at class-level, but it's not working at all when I'm applying at method-level.  What am I doing wrong?  I don't want to intercept every method on a class, but instead flag certain methods with the [Interceptor] attribute.  I've tried marking my methods as virtual, but it still doesn't work.  Here's my code:

This works and all methods are intercepted:

```
[Interceptor(typeof(CacheInterceptor))]
public class Foo : IFoo
{
   public int SomeMethod() { }
}
```

**This is NOT working (attribute is at method level):**

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
   [Interceptor(typeof(CacheInterceptor))]
   public int SomeMethod() { }
}
```

The installer:

```
public class CacheInterceptorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<CacheInterceptor>().LifeStyle.Singleton);

        container.Register(Component
            .For<ICacheProvider>()
            .LifeStyle.Singleton
            .ImplementedBy<CacheProvider>());
    }
}
```

The interceptor:

```
public class CacheInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly ICacheProvider _cacheProvider;

    public CacheInterceptor(ICacheProvider cacheProvider)
    {
        _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
       // do interception stuff
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 7):

You can use custom attribute to select methods to be intercepted:

```
[Interceptor(typeof(CacheInterceptor))]
public class Foo : IFoo
{
   [Cache]
   public int SomeMethod() { }
}
```

Then in `Intercept` method check, if the method has custom attribute:

```
if (invocation.MethodInvocationTarget.IsDefined(typeof(CacheAttribute))) {
  // do interception stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a good workaround.  Hopefully there's a cleaner way to do this though without having to intercept all of the class' methods.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to use the `Interceptor` attribute just on a method. From http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Interceptors.ashx:

> The InterceptorAttribute is defined in a way that allows you to put it not only on classes, but on any other target where custom attribute is allowed, like interface or a method. However **Windsor will ignore the attribute unless it's on component's implementation class**.
>   This permissive behavior was introduced to allow people to add support for other targets by building custom extensions.

(emphasis is mine)

I think something that might be useful in Castle is `IProxyGenerationHook` and/or `IInterceptorSelector`. Some documentation on this: http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.Use-proxy-generation-hooks-and-interceptor-selectors-for-fine-grained-control.ashx

But, I don't see any way of using an `IInterceptorSelector` with the `Interceptor` attribute.

Comment: This makes me sad.  I'm pretty new to AOP but it seems like method-level interceptors would be a nice feature to offer.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a note that with PostSharp, it's much easier to do what you're trying :)